# Removing GRUB 2.0 from Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I had dual booted Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I then deleted the Ubuntu partition using the Windows disk management system. But GRUB hasn't been deleted and it shows the dialogue below every time I start my PC.

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub>
```

[image: grub dialog]

Comment: If UEFI, the answers in https://askubuntu.com/q/63610/590937 should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To restore the default Windows 10 bootloader, do this:

1. Log into Win 10
2. Open "Command Prompt" as Administrator
3. Type `bootsect /nt60 <drive name>: /mbr`

Note that `<drive name>` is the drive letter where the Master Boot Record (MBR) will be updated. For example to update the master boot record on C:, this is the command:

```
bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
```

For more information about `bootsect` command, [Microsoft has you covered](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options)